# Best Way to Include Scripts on a Specific Template Page

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script

This is something that has always confused me and I could use some help.

I want to do four things directly above the closing body tag:

1. include jQuery (WordPress version is fine)
2. include a jQuery plugin dependent on jQuery beneath this
3. initialize the plugin directly underneath this plugin AND avoid conflict issues using $ instead of jQuery
4. do this only on specific page templates or theme files

I understand that I probably should be using wp_enqueue_script, but I'm not sure if I should use that in functions.php or just directly on the page where I want it.

Regarding number 3 I have seen the workarounds such as:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
/* You can safely use $ in this code block to reference jQuery */
});
```

But I'm honestly confused as to how to implement this.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 7):

The following (in your theme's `functions.php`) will register your script, and set jQuery as a dependency. So when you enqueue it, jQuery will also be enqueued.

```
function my_scripts_method() {
   // register your script location, dependencies and version
   wp_register_script('my_custom_script',
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
       array('jquery'),
       '1.0' );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

You can then enqueue your script one of two ways. In your theme's `functions.php` you can use the `template_include` filter the get the template being used using [`is_page_template()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template)

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'my_load_script_for_template', 1000 );
function my_load_script_for_template( $template ){
     if(is_page_template('my-template.php'))
        wp_enqueue_script('my_custom_script');

return $template;
}
```

Alternatively, if you are using 3.3+ and your theme calls [`wp_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) then you can just call `wp_enqueue_script('my_custom_script')` inside the actual template page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you have any advice on the issue of the jQuery variable $ and the correct use of shortcuts to get around this issue?  I'm not quite sure how to handle this.  Is it just the script that fires the plugin on the page that needs this workaround, or do you also have to change the actual jQuery plugin file that is enqueued as well?

Comment: @jw60660 I know it's been a while (6 years) but in case someone else needs it, you can write your .js file like `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { //some_code_here });` and some_code_here can use $ variable instead jQuery

Comment: really thanks. your last paragraph saved me `Alternatively, if you are using 3.3+ and your theme calls wp_footer() then you can just call wp_enqueue_script('my_custom_script') inside the actual template page.`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's still (or ever was) the "best way" since I haven't had time to browse the latest development updates, but I'll start by posting how I do it:

```
function my_slider_script() {
  if ( !is_page_template( 'slider.php' ) )
  return;
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_rotator_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/photo_rotator_tabs.js', array('jquery'));
  }
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_slider_script' )
```

The first two are using the WordPress included js, and the `'my_rotator_script'` is one I've included in my template folder inside a js folder in the theme root called `photo_rotator_tabs.js`. It is only included on the pages that use the slider.php page template.

I think [Scribu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/205/scribu) has written a very detailed post on this subject, but I don't recall the link. I think he uses the `wp_print_scripts` method, or the **"WordPress Ninja"** method. Maybe he'll help you out if my was is obsolete.

Comment: That post was for [short-codes](http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html). :D