# ACF - Attach JS file depending on ACF field

Tags: templates, javascript

When the user creates a "carousel" - layout from a flexible content field within ACF, I need to load all the related jquery js files into the page header.

As far as I understand WP tpl files are not preprocessed. Therefor there is no way to place some kind of markup into the tpl so that the header template will create the necessary script scr loads when a certain tpl is chosen to be outputted.

I found an 6 years old post here:
[Best Way to Include Scripts on a Specific Template Page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45936/best-way-to-include-scripts-on-a-specific-template-page)

Is this still the valid way to do this in WP?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the options in the old post you linked to. If you're already using a custom or child theme, you can also edit `functions.php` and add your custom JS wherever the main theme scripts are enqueued. For me personally it makes things simpler to add all theme CSS and JS in the same call, so if I ever wonder where something's coming from, it is either in `functions.php` or in a plugin somewhere.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_305653_enqueues');
function wpse_305653_enqueues() {
    // theme css
    $version = filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('wpse_305653', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), "$version", 'screen');
    // theme scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('wpse_305653-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts.min.js', array('jquery'), '2.3.4', true);
    // only place this JS on the 'about' page
    if(is_page('about')) {
        wp_register_script('wpse_305653_conditional', get_template_directory_uri() . '/conditional.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('wpse_305653_conditional');
    }
    // only place this JS on singular 'program' CPTs
    if(is_singular('program')) {
        wp_register_script('wpse_305653_conditional2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/conditional2.js', array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('wpse_305653_conditional2');
    }
}
```

You may want to set up a CPT which becomes the only place the ACF fields appear on and therefore the only place the JS needs to enqueue. There are a number of other conditionals you can use here to single out the content you actually need the JS on.